# Sequential access I/O to unit open for direct access

Tags: fortran

I am trying to write a file with direct access as follows:

```
open(unit=11,access='DIRECT',recl=2*mumps_par%N,file=namr,form='unformatted',convert='big_endian')
write(11,rec=1) (dble(vp(i)),i=1,mumps_par%N)
close(11)
```

The `2*` for the record length is because I am using ifort.

When I run this I get the error:

```
forrtl: severe (259): sequential-access I/O to unit open for direct access, unit 11 path/to/file
```

How can I write to this file?

Comment: I think the issue is not related to recl. If the record length was too small you would get a more clear "record overflow" message.

Comment: Yes i do, path to file is where i am writing my file, just didn't want to specifiy it in the question. the thing is that the file is created with a size of 0 bytes and i get this error.

Comment: The error indicates you have done a `write(11)` with no record specifier someplace.

Comment: Please show the complete code. See [mcve].  Are you sure these are the only lines concerning unit 11? I expect there is more. It is better to use variables instead of hardcoded numbers like 11 or 12.

Comment: the only other line is commented like !write(11) N^M

Comment: Unless the character ^M (that comes from windows i think) can mess with the commented line, i really don't see where this error can come from

Comment: So please make a [mcve].